# non-static method compute(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

The code given below is giving the following error:- non-static method compute(int) cannot be referenced from a static context
If i cannot create a method inside main(), what should i do.

```
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = key.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        int a = key.nextInt();
        int b = key.nextInt();
        a=compute(a);
        b=compute(b);
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }   
}
int compute(int a){
    int basea=0, digit;
    int temp=a;
    while(temp>0){
        digit = temp%10;
        temp/=10;
        if(digit>(basea-1))basea=digit+1;
    }
    temp=a;
    a=0;
    int count=0;
    while(temp>0){
        digit = temp%10;
        temp/=10;
        a+=digit*Math.pow(basea,count);
        count++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `static vs non-static` You cannot use non static methods in static methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Declare `compute()` static:

   ```
   static int compute(int a){
   ```
2. Create an instance of `IdeOne` and call `compute()` via that reference:

   ```
   IdeOne ideOne = new IdeOne();
   a = ideOne.compute(a);
   ```

I think it would be a good idea to read through the [Java tutorials on classes and objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a non-static method (which is compute) from a static method (the main).

Change `int compute(int a){` with `static int compute(int a){`

Answer (score 0):

In your case make method `compute` static. Otherwise create an `Ideone` object and call your method on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access `non-static` method from `static` method.
Method you are trying access is instance level method, you can not access instance method/variable without class instance.
You can't access something that doesn't exist. By default non-static method doesn't exist yet, until you create object of that class in which method exist. A static method always exists.

You can access your method by following way :
1. Make your `compute()` method static

```
 int compute(int a){  
  ///rest of your code  
 }
```

2. Create instance of your class `Ideone` and access method by class object.

```
IdeOne obj = new IdeOne();  
obj.compute(a);
obj.compute(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers given here are mainly to make the method `static`, which is fine for a program this size. However, as projects get bigger not everything will be in your main anymore, and thus you get this static/non-static issue on a larger scale as your other classes won't be static.

The solution then becomes to make a class for your `Main`, as such:

```
public class Main {

public static void main( String[] args ) {

Ideone ideone = new Ideone();
```

Then another file which houses your `class Ideone`:

```
public class Ideone {

 Scanner key;

 public Ideone() {

    key = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = key.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        int a = key.nextInt();
        int b = key.nextInt();
        a=compute(a);
        b=compute(b);
        System.out.println(a+b);

   } // end constructor

    int compute(int a){
       int basea=0, digit;
       int temp=a;
       while(temp>0){
         digit = temp%10;
         temp/=10;
         if(digit>(basea-1))basea=digit+1;
    }
    temp=a;
    a=0;
    int count=0;
    while(temp>0){
        digit = temp%10;
        temp/=10;
        a+=digit*Math.pow(basea,count);
        count++;
    }
    return a;
   } // end compute

} // end class
```

As for your main file. What I do will work, but better practice is to follow the code example given here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html

Applying this practice will ensure that you do not have static/non-static issues anywhere in your project, as the only thing that is static is the initialization of your actual code, which then handles all codes / further initilization of other classes (which is all non-static)